# clang -Wglobal-constructors behavior regarding copy/move constructor

Tags: c++11, clang, copy-constructor, constexpr, global

This code produces a warning: "declaration requires a global constructor [-Wglobal-constructors]"

```
// Compile with -Wglobal-constructors
class T {
 public:
  constexpr T(int* p) : ptr_(p) {}
  T(const T& other) : T(other.ptr_) {}

 private:
  int* ptr_;
};

struct MyStruct {
  int x;
  T y;
};
MyStruct s[] {{ 123, nullptr },{ 234, nullptr }};
```

I thought adding `constexpr T(std::nullptr_t) : ptr_(nullptr) {}` would take care of it, but no. Instead, making the copy constructor `constexpr` does, which puzzles me. Same applies to a move constructor, if there was one.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this behavior continues until C++14, but is no longer the case in C++17, where copy elision covers this case.